# How to use threshold to remove false positives?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, threshold

I am using OpenCV EM to segment a image on the HSV domain. Therefore, the segmentation detect some false positives [Highlights in Yellow]. Below, you can see the input image.

[image: Input Image]

And below, the image segmented with false positives.

[image: False Positives]

I try to remove it by using threshold as you can see without success.

[image: Otsu's Example]
[image: Threshold Example]

Any help on how to keep only the Leaf will be appreciated!

Comment: Try cv2.watershed.

Comment: Can you acquire your images with your camera in *”raw”* mode (e.g. Canon CR2, Nikon NEF, Adobe DNG) rather than JPEG?

Comment: I cannot acquire it in "raw: mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "false positives" you see are compression artefacts caused by JPEG compression.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG

You cannot segment this perfectly in Hue or Saturation channel.

Ideally process uncompressed images or use brightness information which usually is preserved in higher frequencies than colour.

Unfortunately you did not provide the actual input image so I cannot help you any further.

Comment: The actual image is the one in the first attachment. However, I will add it separately.

Comment: @Tarcisiofl can you tell me why you have to segment it in the first place? I mean the background is perfectly white and the leaf is not. Actually you already have what you want? or do I miss something here?

Comment: I need to calculate the area of the leaf; however, if I use  cv2.findContours(), it also gets the "false positives"